# C# save last send mail to desktop (as .msg)

Tags: c#, outlook, save, sendmail

I am trying to save last send mail from Outlook to my desktop as .msg format.
But i am getting error with my code in last line of my code as follow:

```
        ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)mail).SaveAs(mydesktop+ "\\Myapplication\\" + subject.Replace(":", "").Replace("/", "").Replace("|", "") + ".msg", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);
```

Error:System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The item has been moved or deleted.'

```
      string mailto = labelControl53.Text + ";" + labelControl56.Text ;
        string cc = "myaccount@mymail.com";
        string subject= labelControl7.Text + "-" + comboBoxEdit1.Text + "-" + textEdit6.Text + " Yüklemesi hk.";

        string mydesktop= Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);


        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application mailat = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mail = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)mailat.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
         mail.To = mailto;
        mail.CC = cc;
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Importance = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
        mail.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
        mail.HTMLBody = getHTMLupload();
        ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)mail).Send();
        ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)mail).SaveAs(mydesktop+ "\\Myapplication\\" + subject.Replace(":", "").Replace("/", "").Replace("|", "") + ".msg", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);
```

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The item has been moved or deleted.'

Comment: what line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Last line ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)mail).SaveAs(mydesktop+ "\\Myapplication\\" + subject.Replace(":", "").Replace("/", "").Replace("|", "") + ".msg", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);

Comment: You can first save the mail item and afterwards send. i think the send method will close / dispose the mail item and therefore it is not accessible anymore

Answer (score 1):

This mail object is released after send so you don't have access to it.
You probably have to add an event handler. Something like this might work.

```
    ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)mail).Send += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_SendEventHandler(SaveSentMail);

    static void SaveSentMail(ref bool Cancel)
    {
       mail.SaveAs(mydesktop+ ....);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the last sent item in Outlook you need to handle the `ItemAdd` event of the `Items` class which comes from the `Sent Items` folder. Typically mail items are placed into the `Sent Items` folder as soon as they are sent. However, users or other add-ins may set the [DeleteAfterSubmit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.deleteaftersubmit) property which sets a Boolean value that is True if a copy of the mail message is not saved upon being sent, and False if a copy is saved in *Sent Items* folder.

Or just call the `SaveAs` before submitting items in Outlook (before the `Send` method).